# How can I use a variable outside the post function?

Tags: node.js, express, dialogflow-es, webhooks

How would I make it so that I can reference my variables name, age and phone outside of the app.post function so I can use them in my const data and use them in the axios.post instruction?

I have tried declaring them at the beginning but it didnt work. The did not get any value.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const ip = process.env.IP || "127.0.0.1";
const axios = require("axios");
//
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    const name = req.body.queryResult.parameters.name;
    const age = req.body.queryResult.parameters.age;
    const phone = req.body.queryResult.parameters.phone;
    //
    res.json(response);
});
const data = [{
    "Name": name,
    "Age": age,
    "Phone": phone
}];
axios.post('https://sheet.best/api/sheets/5296b88f-a7c9-57c2-accc-f445cf323c5e', data);

app.listen(port, ip);
```

Right now the way is coded I get an error "variable is not defined" but if Ideclare them at the beginning the do not get any value.

Comment: Why not just put `data` and the POST request to `sheet.best` inside of your POST handling of `/`?

Comment: That was what I tried first and id does not work.

Comment: That´s what I first did but the POST request did not work. From what I have tried it only works outside but it does not get the values of the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with javascript's synchronous & its 'asynchronous' behavior. `app.post` takes a 'callback'. A 'callback' is a function that will be called in some abritaty amount of time & in your case... when you receive an HTTP request. When your code is executed, your `axios.post` function will execute before the callback passed to `app.post`. So all the keys in `data` will be never be defined... Not to mention variables; `name, age, phone` are never declared in the scope they are being used.

I would suggest creating a generic function that takes arguments `name, age, phone` and executes the `axios.post` logic. Therefore you can reuse this function on each `app.post`. I've created a code snippet below of what you could do. Its using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) to manage asynchronous activity.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const ip = process.env.IP || "127.0.0.1";
const axios = require("axios");

app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

async function postData(name, age, phone) {
    const data = [
        {
            Name: name,
            Age: age,
            Phone: phone
        }
    ];

    const result = await axios.post(
        "https://sheet.best/api/sheets/5296b88f-a7c9-57c2-accc-f445cf323c5e",
        data
    );

    return result;
}

app.post("/", async function(req, res) {
    const name = req.body.queryResult.parameters.name;
    const age = req.body.queryResult.parameters.age;
    const phone = req.body.queryResult.parameters.phone;

    const result = await postData(name, age, phone);

    return res.json(result);
});

app.listen(port, ip);
```